# direct URL login to dd-wrt web interface

Tags: web, interface, router, dd-wrt

Anyone know how to make direct login URL for dd-wrt web interface.

Something like:

```
http://192.168.1.1/index.asp?user=root&pass=admin
```

If there is no solution please give me php example script. Thanks.

Comment: nevermind I got it... http://root:admin@192.168.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this way, for more h

```
    http://root:admin@192.168.1.1/Status_Router.asp
```